# How can i get number of Sharepoint Pages or documents viewers using HTTP request through Power Automate?

Tags: rest, http, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

How can i get number of Sharepoint Pages or documents viewers using HTTP request through Power Automate?
I can't seem to find a way or answer on how send an HTTP request to SharePoint using power automate to get the site usage

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using the Graph API in Power Automate. There are SharePoint site usage methods available in the Graph API.

Probably these two methods are good to start with:
[reportRoot: getSharePointSiteUsagePages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getsharepointsiteusagepages?view=graph-rest-1.0)
[reportRoot: getSharePointSiteUsageDetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getsharepointsiteusagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0)